# How to parse JSON request body in Sinatra just once and expose it to all routes?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I am writing an API and it receives a JSON payload as the request body.

To get at it currently, I am doing something like this:

```
post '/doSomething' do
    request.body.rewind
    request_payload = JSON.parse request.body.read

    #do something with request_payload
    body request_payload['someKey']
end
```

What's a good way to abstract this away so that I don't need to do it for each route? Some of my routes are more complicated than this, and as a result the request.body would get reread and reparsed several times per route with this approach, which I want to avoid.

Is there some way to make the request_payload just magically available to routes? Like this:

```
post '/doSomething' do
    #do something with request_payload, it's already parsed and available
    body request_payload['someKey']
end
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use a sinatra before handler:

```
before do
  request.body.rewind
  @request_payload = JSON.parse request.body.read
end
```

this will expose it to the current request handler.  If you want it exposed to all handlers, put it in a superclass and extend that class in your handlers.

Comment: That was my first instinct, but will this work with async-sinatra? I'm afraid subsequent requests might override it while the previous ones are still in-flight?

Comment: Sinatra *should* create a new instance of each handler per request, so provided you use an instance level variable it should be ok.  We use a similar scheme and have seen no evidence of race conditions under load.

Comment: The `before` filter [can be](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Filters) predicated on route patterns but seemingly not HTTP methods. Bummer - doing this for only POSTs is a plausible use case.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use Rack Middleware to parse it. See https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib Just `use Rack::PostBodyContentTypeParser` when initializing your Sinatra class.

Comment: Since `rack-contrib` 2.2.0, `PostBodyContentTypeParser` has been deprecated in favor of `JSONBodyParser`, much faster and modular.

Answer (score 6):

Like this working for sinatra 1.4.5

```
before do
  if request.body.size > 0
    request.body.rewind
    @params = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body.read)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
before do
  request.body.rewind
  @request_payload = JSON.parse(request.body.read, symbolize_names: true)
end
```

So you can also symbolize_names while parsing JSON request body, this will give you access to your nested params like this `@request_payload[:user]`

Answer (score 3):

You can parse your JSON post body as a `Hash` with `Rack::PostBodyContentTypeParser` from https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib:

```rb
require 'rack/contrib/post_body_content_type_parser'

class Api < Sinatra::Application
  use Rack::PostBodyContentTypeParser
  ...
end
```

You can even pass a custom block to `Rack::PostBodyContentTypeParser` to parse the JSON as symbols instead of strings:

```rb
a_proc = proc { |body| JSON.parse(body, symbolize_names: true, create_additions: false) }
use Rack::PostBodyContentTypeParser, &a_proc
```

Comment: I believe you answer is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34730743/6320039) with a few more details. Maybe you should edit it rather than creating a new answer?

Comment: @UlysseBN thanks for the suggestion, but I was getting a `Suggested edit queue is full` error, for this reason I decided to create a new answer