# JSON from Javascript Object to Ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, json, sinatra

I'm sending an object from Javascript to a Sinatra POST route. I'm using the 'stringify' method to convert my js object to JSON. The JSON being sent is like so (according to the dev tools in chrome):

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":"3"}:
```

I have my route in Sinatra setup like so:

```
post '/results' do
    results = JSON.parse(params.to_json, symbolize_names: true)
end
```

I can't figure how to access the keys in Ruby once I parse the JSON. Is there a better way to do so, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that if you are sending the `JSON` in the `POST` body - you should access it from `request.body`, and not from `params` (see this question: [How to parse JSON request body in Sinatra just once and expose it to all routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049569/how-to-parse-json-request-body-in-sinatra-just-once-and-expose-it-to-all-routes)):

```
post '/results' do
  request.body.rewind
  results = JSON.parse(request.body.read, symbolize_names: true)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access it like an associative array:

```
results["a"]
results["b"]
...
```

Comment: I get nil when I try and access it like that.

Comment: @jmcharnes try removing the symbolize_names parameter.