# Why won't this POST request send a JSON string to the server?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, post, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra. I've got a button that sends a JSON-formatted string to the server by making a POST request. Only problem is, the JSON string isn't getting to the server.

Here's `index.erb`:

```
<input id="post-button" type="button" value="Send POST request">
```

Here's `script.js`:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var btn = document.getElementById('post-button');
  btn.onclick = function(){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var reqObj = {
      name: 'Joe',
      age: '100'
    };
    var reqJSON = JSON.stringify(reqObj);

    req.open('POST','/post_target',true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    req.send(reqJSON);
  }
}
```

And finally, `main.rb`:

```
get '/' do 
    erb :index
end

post '/post_target' do 
    p params
end
```

When I click the button and check Firebug, I see that the browser sent a POST request. But when I check the Ruby console, it prints `{}` for `params`. If it worked right, I guess `params` would show a JSON object in string form, along with whatever else it would show.

I'm running Sinatra on my machine, at address `http://localhost:4567`.

What am I doing wrong? If I need to do the request with jQuery, I can do that, but can it be done with "vanilla" JavaScript?

Comment: Hmm...could it be because you are setting the request's content-type to JSON but are actually sending a string? What happens when you set the request content-type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded?
(Disclaimer: I'm not really sure how Sinatra works - hence posting a comment instead of an answer)

Comment: Nah, removing the content-type gets the same result when the code runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"params" is most likely looking for URL encoded query string values. You want the Body content of the post, not the params.

See [How to parse JSON request body in Sinatra just once and expose it to all routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049569/how-to-parse-json-request-body-in-sinatra-just-once-and-expose-it-to-all-routes)

Comment: Ah, so in `main.rb` I need to use `JSON.parse()` on `request.body.read`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the JSON body:

```
parsed_params = JSON.parse( request.body.read, symbolize_names:true )
```

Comment: This code gives me an error: `ERROR TypeError: can't convert Array into String`

Answer (score 1):

Alex Hill is right. And the the post he mentioned show one way to solve it.

An other way is to use rack/contrib:

require it:

```
require 'rack'
require 'rack/contrib'
```

add the middleware

```
use Rack::PostBodyContentTypeParser
```

source: http://jaywiggins.com/2010/03/using-rack-middleware-to-parse-json/